# Mount CD/DVD as external harddrive

Tags: windows, dvd, cd

I'm trying to use CDs and DVDs with Steam to play games off them. The only issue is that when you eject the CD, the list of installed games does not update like it would with a normal external drive.

So, is there a way to make a CD or DVD appear as a harddrive, that also disappears when I eject it?

I've tried using disk management to mount it to a folder on another harddrive, but it doesn't work for this situation since the directory doesn't disappear. It also means the actual harddrive cannot be used to store games.

To try and make it easier to understand, [here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2TG8.png)

Comment: why not just image the CDs/DVD's as files on your harddrive, then mount and umount the images as necessary?

Comment: @BlindSpots Convenience. I can also just manually remove and add the library folders in steam, but computers are made to automate this stuff.

Comment: I don't follow.

Comment: Well, maybe you can try having VHD(X) files (which contain you game files) on the optical disk.

Comment: @TomYan Sorry for the late reply! Technical difficulties with my burner. I can put a VHD on the DVD but cannot attach it afterwards via disk managemnt due to "a file system limitation". If it did work it would've been the perfect solution. So close yet so far. Bummer :/

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it helps if you format the VHD(X) with UDF (by using `diskpart`) and also make sure the optical disc uses UDF (instead of ISO9660) as its filesystem.

Comment: @TomYan That sadly didn't do it. The issue crops up even with a completely uninitialized and unformatted VHD as well. It's not the VHD format that's causing the incompatability